# The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip' Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, mvcjqgrid

I was trying to implement the `jQgrid` using `MvcjQgrid` and i got this exception.

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.
```

Though OrdeyBy is used before Skip method why it is generating the exception? How can it be solved?

I encountered the exception in the controller:

```
public ActionResult GridDataBasic(GridSettings gridSettings)
        {          
            var jobdescription = sm.GetJobDescription(gridSettings);
            var totalJobDescription = sm.CountJobDescription(gridSettings);

            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalJobDescription / gridSettings.PageSize + 1,
                page = gridSettings.PageIndex,
                records = totalJobDescription,
                rows = (
                    from j in jobdescription
                    select new
                    {
                        id = j.JobDescriptionID,
                        cell = new[] 
                    { 
                        j.JobDescriptionID.ToString(), 
                        j.JobTitle,
                        j.JobType.JobTypeName,
                        j.JobPriority.JobPriorityName,
                        j.JobType.Rate.ToString(),
                        j.CreationDate.ToShortDateString(),
                         j.JobDeadline.ToShortDateString(),

                    }
                    }).ToArray()
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**GetJobDescription Method** and **CountJobDescription Method**

```
public int CountJobDescription(GridSettings gridSettings)
        {
            var jobdescription = _dataContext.JobDescriptions.AsQueryable();

            if (gridSettings.IsSearch)
            {
                jobdescription = gridSettings.Where.rules.Aggregate(jobdescription, FilterJobDescription);
            }
            return jobdescription.Count();
        }

        public IQueryable<JobDescription> GetJobDescription(GridSettings gridSettings)
        {
            var jobdescription = orderJobDescription(_dataContext.JobDescriptions.AsQueryable(), gridSettings.SortColumn, gridSettings.SortOrder);

            if (gridSettings.IsSearch)
            {
                jobdescription = gridSettings.Where.rules.Aggregate(jobdescription, FilterJobDescription);
            }

            return jobdescription.Skip((gridSettings.PageIndex - 1) * gridSettings.PageSize).Take(gridSettings.PageSize);
        }
```

And Finally **FilterJobDescription and OrderJobDescription**

```
private static IQueryable<JobDescription> FilterJobDescription(IQueryable<JobDescription> jobdescriptions, Rule rule)
        {
            if (rule.field == "JobDescriptionID")
            {
                int result;
                if (!int.TryParse(rule.data, out result))
                    return jobdescriptions;
                return jobdescriptions.Where(j => j.JobDescriptionID == Convert.ToInt32(rule.data));

            }

// Similar Statements

            return jobdescriptions;
        }



private IQueryable<JobDescription> orderJobDescription(IQueryable<JobDescription> jobdescriptions, string sortColumn, string sortOrder)
        {
            if (sortColumn == "JobDescriptionID")
                return (sortOrder == "desc") ? jobdescriptions.OrderByDescending(j => j.JobDescriptionID) : jobdescriptions.OrderBy(j => j.JobDescriptionID);

            return jobdescriptions;
        }
```

Comment: But you don't order always, only if `sortColumn == "JobDescriptionID"`, do you?

Comment: Does it matter? By the way, i have several other order statements.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The exception means that you *always* need a sorted input if you apply `Skip`, also in the case that the user doesn't click on a column to sort by. I could imagine that no sort column is specified when you open the grid view for the first time before the user can even click on a column header. To catch this case I would suggest to define some default sorting that you want when no other sorting criterion is given, for example:

```
switch (sortColumn)
{
    case "JobDescriptionID":
        return (sortOrder == "desc")
            ? jobdescriptions.OrderByDescending(j => j.JobDescriptionID)
            : jobdescriptions.OrderBy(j => j.JobDescriptionID);

    case "JobDescriptionTitle":
        return (sortOrder == "desc")
            ? jobdescriptions.OrderByDescending(j => j.JobDescriptionTitle)
            : jobdescriptions.OrderBy(j => j.JobDescriptionTitle);

    // etc.

    default:
        return jobdescriptions.OrderBy(j => j.JobDescriptionID);
}
```

**Edit**

About your follow-up problems according to your comment: You cannot use `ToString()` in a LINQ to Entities query. And the next problem would be that you cannot create a `string` array in a query. I would suggest to load the data from the DB with their native types and then convert afterwards to strings (and to the string array) in memory:

```
rows = (from j in jobdescription
        select new
        {
            JobDescriptionID = j.JobDescriptionID,
            JobTitle = j.JobTitle,
            JobTypeName = j.JobType.JobTypeName,
            JobPriorityName = j.JobPriority.JobPriorityName,
            Rate = j.JobType.Rate,
            CreationDate = j.CreationDate,
            JobDeadline = j.JobDeadline
        })
        .AsEnumerable() // DB query runs here, the rest is in memory
        .Select(a => new
        {
            id = a.JobDescriptionID,
            cell = new[] 
            { 
                a.JobDescriptionID.ToString(), 
                a.JobTitle,
                a.JobTypeName,
                a.JobPriorityName,
                a.Rate.ToString(),
                a.CreationDate.ToShortDateString(),
                a.JobDeadline.ToShortDateString()
            }
        })
        .ToArray()
```

Comment: That exception is now gone. But new exception is encountered in the controller as `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`Now how to convert `JobDescriptionID` and other attributes into string then?

Comment: @aneal: See my Edit. (It has actually nothing to do with your original question.)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same type of problem after sorting using some code from **Adam Anderson** that accepted a generic sort string in OrderBy.

After getting this excpetion, i did lots of research and found that very clever fix:

```
var query = SelectOrders(companyNo, sortExpression);

return Queryable.Skip(query, iStartRow).Take(iPageSize).ToList();
```

Hope that helps !

SP

Comment: I have that generic implementaiton in my solution , tried your fix but it didn't work , by the way what current change would do