# IPagedList // IEnumerable trouble

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I got a trouble in my asp.net proyect. I want to paginate my table but i'm unable to launch my site.

That's the problem:

- I created entity model into 'Context' folder with getters and setters
  of my table
- Then i generated the controller with vs
- I modify controller with this code

  ```
      public ActionResult Index(int? page)
      {

      var firmas = from f in db.Firmas select f;
      if (Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
      {
          page = 1;
      }
      int pageSize = 2;
      int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

      return View(firmas.ToPagedList(pageSize, pageNumber));
      }
  ```

And i got this into cshtml index

```
@*@model IEnumerable<actiTest2.Context.Firmas>*@

@model PagedList.IPagedList<actiTest2.Controllers.FirmasController>

@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
```

That's the point, if i call model IEnumerable, program crash cause need IPagedList, but if i call IPagedList program say that 'FirmasController' does not contain a definition for my model display.

What could i do? Merge Controller and auto-generated code with get/set errs?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: After apply the 'smoksnes' solution i got a new problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2brzG.png

Comment: Its `@model PagedList.IPagedList<actiTest2.Context.Firmas>` (assuming `db.Firmas` returns objects that are typeof `Firmas`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your model in your view to (first line):

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<actiTest2.Context.Firmas>
```

When you use `@model PagedList.IPagedList<actiTest2.Controllers.FirmasController>` your're trying to use your controller as a model.

So your view should look like this:

```
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc
@model PagedList.IPagedList<actiTest2.Context.Firmas>

<p> Content here </p>
```

And in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    // Order the collection before skipping.
    var firmas = db.Firmas.OrderBy(x => x.Name); // Or some property.
    if (Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    int pageSize = 2;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

    return View(firmas.ToPagedList(pageSize, pageNumber));
}
```

More info about error here:

[The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip' Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593386/the-method-orderby-must-be-called-before-the-method-skip-exception)

> The exception means that you always need a sorted input if you apply
>   Skip, also in the case that the user doesn't click on a column to sort
>   by.

And specifically for [`ToPagedList()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264323/pagedlist-error-the-method-orderby-must-be-called-before-the-method-skip).

Comment: Now i got a problem into controller when i return the View in index method. NotSupportedException, i edit 1st post to show an image.

Comment: What's the problem you get in the controller?

Comment: Posted image on intial post